# Mysterious Network issues with posts. Wifi Works, Cell doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, post

I keep getting a timeout with sending post requests when my actual device is on 3G or 4G. However, when I'm on wifi, the post request is immediately received on the server side.

Here's my code that involves the post request. I'm getting a `Optional("The request timed out.")`. I don't think the session length should be a problem since it times out after a long time and the data that is being sent is just a username with a password. Any thoughts?

I run a flask server, but I don't think it's relevant so I didn't include its code.

```
       if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            let url = NSURL(string: base_address + taglocation_address)!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            print("starting task")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
                if error != nil{
                    self.statusLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:  JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                    print("doing something")
                    if let responseJSON = json as? [String: String] {
                        print(responseJSON)
                        self.statusLabel.text = responseJSON["status"]

                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    self.statusLabel.text = error.localizedDescription
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you do request.allowsCellularAccess=true

Comment: It happens to work...Thanks! Can you post this answer so I can give you points?

Comment: Yes, sure. I will post an answer.

Comment: For some reason, it just stopped working (because we deployed). I added the request.allowsCellularAccess = true. Is there any other reason it could not be working?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are far too many possible combinations for "why it could not be working," to fit inside a comment. You are going to have to get creative at debugging. Can you ping the web service you are trying to reach? You mentioned the your web service is consistent on wifi, is it say equally consistent on other cell phone providers networks like Verizon or AT&T?

Comment: The request isn't even being sent out if it's on cell. Any other thoughts?

Comment: For example, the starting task prints, but none of the inside print statements execute.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that I was using a computer with a firewall that allowed same network traffic. But, cell data is on a different network (i.e. 3G 4G)

Comment: Aha! Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `NSMutableURLRequest` object, try adding `allowsCellularAccess` property and set it to true. Refer to my code below.

```
 if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            let url = NSURL(string: base_address + taglocation_address)!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            request.allowsCellularAccess=true //Add this line
            print("starting task")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
                if error != nil{
                    self.statusLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:  JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                    print("doing something")
                    if let responseJSON = json as? [String: String] {
                        print(responseJSON)
                        self.statusLabel.text = responseJSON["status"]

                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    self.statusLabel.text = error.localizedDescription
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```